# Zoom Level over 20 in UWP maps control

Tags: uwp-maps

I need zoom level 21 in maps. I added map control following MSDN article ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/overlay-tiled-images#overlay-tiles-from-a-web-service) => Overlay tiles from a web service) and also followed instruction for "[Replace the default map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/overlay-tiled-images#replace-the-default-map)" at page bottom.

As I see, map zooms only to level 20 and that also is not 20, it is actually zoomed 19.

I tried setting ZoomLevelRange for tile source, but that does also not help, code:

> var dataSource = new HttpMapTileDataSource("http://www.webservicename.com/z={zoomlevel}&x={x}&y={y}");
>
> MyMap.Style = MapStyle.None;
>
> var tileSource = new MapTileSource(dataSource) {
>
> > ```
> >    ZoomLevelRange = new MapZoomLevelRange
> >    {
> >           Max = 21,
> >           Min = 1
> >    },
> >    Layer = MapTileLayer.BackgroundReplacement
> > ```
> >
> > };
>
> MyMap.TileSources.Add(tileSource);

Is it possible to have zoom level 21 for custom tile source?

Thanks,

Amir

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't think it's possible to zoom in farther than level 20.

Each of the zoom levels has it's own set of "tiles" that are needed to render the map at that zoom level. Likely, the tiles to render zoom levels closer than 20 don't exist, so it wouldn't be possible to render the map at that zoom level.