# UWP Map Control show nothing when zooming up

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I set the Map Control's initial zoom level to 10.

After I use mouse wheel to zoom it up,it shows nothing.

If I set the accuarcy,can this be fixed?

I just try to get a high-accuracy map.

Are there any good third part map control to recommend?

code in xaml is

```
<Map:MapControl Name="map"
   ZoomLevel="10" Loaded="map_Loaded"
/>
```

code in cs is

```
 Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
                geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 10;
                geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
                Geoposition pos = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();                                     
                Geopoint myLocation = pos.Coordinate.Point;
                // Set the map location.
                map.Center = myLocation;
```

I have read these:[Zoom Level over 20 in UWP maps control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38844510/zoom-level-over-20-in-uwp-maps-control)  and https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/guidelines-and-checklist-for-detecting-location

Comment: What did you mean about "shows noting"? The maximum and minimum values of ZoomLevel depend on the type of map view: 2D, 3D, or Streetside. 2D range:1-20 3D range: 1-20 Streetside range: 24-26. Please make sure that if the ZoomLevel is larger than the max ZoomLevel value when mouse wheeling. You could use [ZoomLevelChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Maps_MapControl_ZoomLevelChanged) event to detect it.

Comment: It's show empty.

Comment: Please try to run the official [MapControl sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl) to see if you still face this issue.

Comment: I have read the code but it have not say any about zoom.And it also show nothing with zoom.

Comment: My app can run in my colleague that can show the map when zoom.I think it's ms have a bad speed in Chinese that should use more time to load it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The ms map have a bad speed in Chinese that it should spend more time to load.

When the map have nothing ,you can try use Setting->App->Offline map to download it.

[image]

The good way is use google map or baidu map .The first is use in foreign and the other is use in Chinese.

In Chinese,you need consider network problems .I have encountered a lot of problems because the network is not good.

The ms map cant tell me when it start downloading, when it is complete.

I recommend using webView to open an online map.

Answer (score 0):

If the map is blue, then please check the 'myLocation' value. If that is (0,0), then you are probably in the ocean.

Comment: Thx,but you have no understand it.